# Insert/Delete/Update With ZK MDB Microsoft Access database File Not work

Tags: ms-access, crud, vb.net-2010

I cant insert/update/delete to the access mdb file on the file mdb i saw it Readonly, Does it the reason that i cant use command with it?

Note: The mdb file is Readonly
Note: The software come with the ZK Fingerprint Product code: 'B3-C/USB'  "Attendance Management system" can work with the database.mdb, so that i think i can too.

I try this:

```
    Try
        cn.Open()

        commandText = "INSERT INTO USERINFO(USERID,Name) VALUES(2,'Madaraz')"
        SqlDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(commandText, cn)
        SqlComBuilder = New OleDbCommand(commandText, cn)
        SqlComBuilder.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch er As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & er.Message)
    Finally
        cn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

When i try to run the above code it not even get error but it has nothing happens i don know what it going on.

I hope Expert can help me with it thx you guy in advance.

Comment: Have you tried simply opening the database file in Access?

Answer (score 1):

If the database file is read only, it won't work. Remove the read only attribute from mdb file.

Comment: @BongNakMadaraz Right-click on the .mdb file and choose `Properties`. Make sure that the `Read-only` checkbox is empty.